# Where is the executable?

Tags: bash, which

I have this command that I run.  Let's call it `foo`.
I can execute `foo` without specify the full path to `foo` like so:

```
$ foo
missing args
```

I suspect `foo` is a bash script so I want to look at the source code in `foo`, but when I do `which foo` I get the standard error message:

```
which: no foo in (/usr/local/bin ...removed for brevity ...)
```

What gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `type` built-in, which indicates how the argument would be interpreted if used as a command name, e.g. as a function, built-in, a binary (under `$PATH`)

```
$ f() { echo foo; }
$ type f
f is a function
f ()
{
    echo foo
}
$ type type
type is a shell builtin
$ type grep
grep is /usr/bin/grep
$ alias z='echo zee zee'
$ type z
z is aliased to `echo zee zee'
```

See also [Why not use `"which"`? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/112235) for a more detailed write-up on the subject.